# 2 errores sin sentido en una misma función

Tags: c++

En el siguiente código me aparecen 2 errores a los cuales no encuentro ningún sentido, espero puedan ayudarme.

```
int CPartit::PuntuaCistella(ETir tir)
{
    if(tir == e_lliure)
    {
        return 1;
    }else if(tir == e_camp ){
        return 2;
    }else(tir==e_triple ){ //expected ';' before '{' token

        return 3;
    }
} //control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Gracias

Comment: ` //expected ';' before '{' token` Deberías leer un libro elemental del lenguaje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`else` no admite condiciones de ningun tipo. La sintaxis es:

```
if( condicion1 )
  // codigo a ejecutar si se cumple condicion1
else
  // codigo a ejecutar si no se cumple condicion1
```

En tu caso estás concatenando dos `if-else`, por lo que deberían quedar así:

```
if( condicion1 )
  // codigo a ejecutar si se cumple condicion1
else if( condicion ")
  // codigo a ejecutar si se cumple condicion2 pero no condicion1
else
  // codigo a ejecutar si no se cumple condicion1 ni condicion2
```

Nota que el último `else` no tiene condiciones. Aplicado esto a tu código quedaría así:

```
if(tir == e_lliure)
{
    return 1;
}else if(tir == e_camp ){
    return 2;
}else{
    return 3;
}
```

El segundo error que comentas está íntimamente relacionado con este que te comento. Lo que sucede es que el compilador está entendiendo  `(tir==e_triple) { return 3; }` como una función y claro, se encuentra con una función mal construída y que la función principal tiene una ruta que no retorna ningún valor.

Comment: Toda la razón, habría alguna forma de solo ejecutar la función si tir fuese igual a alguna de las 3 opciones?

Comment: @ElPatrón lo siento pero no te entiendo

Comment: @ElPatrón usa un `switch`.

Comment: Me refiero a si habría alguna forma de añadir el si tir==e_triple return 3 en la función

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Gracias, es buena idea.

Comment: @ElPatrón el `switch` únicamente funcionará si `ETir` es un alias de una variable numérica (`int`, `short`, etc). Si no prueba a anidar más if-else: `else if( tir==e_triple){ return 3; }`

Comment: Entonces creo que no funcionaria el switch porque ETir es un enumerador, gracias por la aclaración

Comment: @ElPatrón los `enum` se traducen a tipos numéricos. En ese caso si te valdría

Comment: Vaya muchas gracias, aún estoy muy verde. Que me recomiendas en ese caso un switch o añadir else if? @eferion

Comment: @ElPatrón si trabajas con enumerados mejor `switch`. Lo único que tienes que tener cuidado con los `break`, pero son más limpios en estos casos.